# The current roman font does not contain the Arabic (polyglossia)

Tags: verbatim, polyglossia, arabic

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Traditional Arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}





\begin{document}
هيكل الوثيقة  documentclass  وينقسم الى قسمين قسم الحزم  يحتوي عادةً على أوامر تؤثر على المستند بأكمله وقسم إرفاق نص المستند بين أمرين يحددان بداية ونهاية المستند الفعلي
\begin{verbatim}



\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\begin{document}
     
\end{document}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A current polyglossia will give a better error message:

```
! Package polyglossia Error: The current latin monospace font does not contain 
the "Arabic" script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \arabicfonttt with \newfontfamily command.
```

You need a definition for the typewriter family used in the verbatim (and perhaps also for the sans family). So use

```
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Traditional Arabic}
```

Comment: \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Traditional Arabic}   is exist but error

Comment: `\arabicfonttt` <--- ttt at the end.

Comment: please rewrite all package

Comment: @IlyesBoudas I extended the answer.